# Loading Array From .Plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, plist

I'm trying to load my array from an array in my .Plist but its not working.

The plist looks like this:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"DiseasePropertyList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *rootLevel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.myArray = rootLevel;
[rootLevel release];
```

Comment: You look dangerous with that list!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this. Please change file name.
It works fine.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *recentFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"recent.plist"];
NSArray *history = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:recentFilePath];
```

Comment: Another way: ` NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"DiseasePropertyList" withExtension: @"plist"];
 NSArray* myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL: url];`

Answer (score 5):

Your plist is actually a dictionary. The array is the object of that dictionary for key "Array". You can make the plist into an array in Xcode 4 by selecting "Array" and cutting (CMD-x), and then pasting into the empty plist (CMD v).

Comment: I would say this is most likely the issue. You can also view the plist as source and just remove the `<dict>` and `</dict>` tags from the file (I do it all the time).

Comment: Also remove the <key> .. </key> tag after the starting tag <dict>.. this will definitely solves problem for me....

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *pathStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [settingsBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourproject.plist"]; 
NSDictionary *settingsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
```

and just check the description of settingsDict. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

If your plist file is in your application bundle, the easiest is this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename_without_extension" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method it worked fine for me.

```
NSArray *country= [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CountryList" ofType:@"plist"]];
```